# MFC: Move a rectangle on client area

Tags: mfc, mouseevent

I want to create an MFC application that move an rectangle in the client area by hold left mouse and move to new position. But the rectangle move too fast although I move the mouse slowly.
My code here:

```
class CEmpWnd : public CFrameWnd
{
protected:
    POINT lpStart, rpStart, oPoint;
    bool clicked;
public:
    CEmpWnd(void);
    virtual ~CEmpWnd(void);
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    afx_msg void OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};


int CEmpWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    lpStart.x = 0;
    lpStart.y = 0;
    rpStart.x = 100;
    rpStart.y = 100;
    clicked = false;
    if (CWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;
    SetTimer(ID_TIMER, 250, NULL);
    SetWindowText(L"Phùng Khánh Hiên ");
    return 0;
}

void CEmpWnd::OnPaint()
{
    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting
    Rectangle(dc, lpStart.x, lpStart.y, rpStart.x, rpStart.y);     //Draw a rectangle
}

void CEmpWnd::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if(point.x >= lpStart.x && point.x <= rpStart.x && point.y >= lpStart.y && point.y <=   rpStart.y)     //If click on rectangle area
    {
        clicked = true;
        oPoint = point;
    }
}

void CEmpWnd::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if(clicked == true)
    {
        lpStart.x += (point.x - oPoint.x);             //Increase left-top and right-bot Points
        rpStart.x += (point.x - oPoint.x);          
        lpStart.y += (point.y - oPoint.y);
        rpStart.y += (point.y - oPoint.y);
        lpStart.x = max(0, lpStart.x);                 //Keep current size of rectangle.
        lpStart.y = max(0, lpStart.y);
        rpStart.x = max(100, rpStart.x);
        rpStart.y = max(100, rpStart.y);
        Invalidate();                                  //Eraze old Rectangle and redraw new one.
    }
}

void CEmpWnd::OnLButtonUp(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    clicked = false;                                  //Release drawing.
}
```

I am new in MFC. Can someone help me please ? Thank everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you always add the total Change again to the current Position.

(point.x - oPoint.x) is the complete horizontal change.
But lpStart contains always the current rectangle coords.
Save the rectangle coords of lpStart also as a oRect when the button is clieked.

```
CRect newRect = oRect;
newRect.OffsetRect(point.x - oPoint.x, point.y - oPoint.y);
lpStart = newRect;
Invalidate();
```

Or set oPoint to Point after you moved the rectangle. with tis trick you always track only the relative changes.

```
...your code
// Save the new oPoint to makle the movements relative
oPoint = Point;
Invalidate();
```